# AWS EC2 | increase/decrease RAM dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, memory

Is there a way to choose a VM or other service in AWS to dynamically add memory in case of extra load?

I am going to deploy a small EC2 in AWS. And I don't need too much memory because it will be loaded only while downloading reports from DB. So basically I am looking for the cheapest possible solution, as the machine will be idle 90 % of the time.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to dynamically adjust EC2 instance memory without changing instance type and stopping and starting the instance. To avoid running an instance idle you can start and stop it on a schedule using [AWS Instance Schedule](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/). Alternatively, you can run [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) on a schedule or on an event.

Comment: Dear Alex, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @AlexD's answer, [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) is a good tool if you can have it perform the task you need to. Other options include using a Docker container running in [ECS Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/what-is-fargate.html) (which is also 'serverless'), or using a small EC2 instance with the CloudWatch Agent installed (to report memory usage) and setting up [AutoScaling](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/autoscaling/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried that the instance may run out of memory and have processes crashing, instead of adjusting the instance size you could also add a swap partition to it so that the operating system can offload process memory to disk in case it runs out of physical memory. This will come at a performance hit though as EBS storage is attached via the network and not all instance types allow you to use instance storage that is located on the physical server where your instance is being hosted. But in some cases it would be a better scenario than having your processes crash.